# Disable hour(s) in bootstrap-daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I've been using this for my date range Picker: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

It's pretty straight forward but I can't seem to find a way to disable particular hour(s) in the time dropdown. e.g. I would like to disable the 12 and 1 in the selection. Has anyone crossed the same thing ?

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pp2zbL8/2/) :

And here's a quick look:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="Date2"]').daterangepicker({
          minDate: getCurrentDateToday()+" 8:30 AM",
        dateLimit: { "days": 1},
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        locale: {format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'}
    },
    function(start, end, label)
    {
        var hr = end.diff(start, 'hours');
        $('#TotalHrs').val(hr);
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean `minDate: getCurrentDateToday()+" 2:00 AM",` ? http://jsfiddle.net/9pp2zbL8/1/

Comment: no sir, I need to set the start date that way(in the fiddle). What I need to happen is to get rid of the 12 and 1 in the selection while having the getCurrentDateToday()+" 8:30 AM"